# password doesnt update nodejs bcrypt

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

In the following code I'm using bcrypt to hash a password and store it in a user array. After the initial creation with   `post => /api/register`, the login works correctly and returns the welcome message. after updating the password with a new string with post `/api/register/1,` `the password does get updated, but the login fails for either of the passwords created. Thanks for looking.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const users = [];

app.post("/api/register", async (req, res) => {
  // do the registration here

  const user = {
    id: users.length + 1,
    name: req.body.name,
    password: req.body.password,
  };

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); 
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  users.push(user);
  res.send(user);
});
app.post("/api/register/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const user = users.find((u) => u.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
  if (!user) return res.status(404).send("user not found");
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); 
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  res.send(user);
});

app.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
  const user = users.find((u) => u.name === req.body.name);
  if (!user) return res.status(404).send("user was not found");
  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
  if (validPassword) res.send("welcome" + user.name);
  else res.send(user);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: After `user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);` you must update the user contained in your array `users`. Beware to avoid duplication removing the old reference to user, and adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating a user variable locally but not updating the value in your global array so try this:

```
app.post("/api/register/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const userIndex = users.findIndex((u) => u.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
  if (!userIndex) return res.status(404).send("user not found");
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); 
  users[userIndex].password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
  res.send(users[userIndex]);
});
```

Comment: thanks so much for looking at this, after hours of staring at this I just found my problem. bcrypt.hash(user.password) should be bcrypt.hash(req.body.password)

Comment: I tried your solution and it returns "user not found", I think what was happening was that I was rehashing an already hashed password , user.password instead of the new password. That's why neither of them would work. I'm new to this,how do i give you an upvote?

Comment: Updated the answer with that. actually I missed that as well.

Comment: And also without updating object in users array it won't work if you are just updating the user variable locally. Or is it working without that?

Answer (score 0):

after hours of staring at this I just found my problem. bcrypt.hash(user.password) should be bcrypt.hash(req.body.password)